# Adding an element to a website using classes

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

What I'm trying to make is a userscript that adds an element to a page (Presume a button, though I'm having trouble adding anything in the first place).

So I have a website with a really long DOM Structure and most elements use classes. The structure is as follows:

```
<body class="...">
 <div class="pageContainer">
  <div class="container body">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
     <article>
      <section class="forumIndex">
       <ol class="list list-ideas">
        <li class="listItem idea idea-list">
         <div class="uvIdeaVoteBadge">
```

Now I want to add something before the `<div class="uvIdeaVoteBadge">`, though can't figure out how to.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: What's the problem? Seems a trivial, basic task.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this? The user script? The selector? Expanding the DOM? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @Peter Why would you want to use jQuery for such a simple task?

Comment: Easiest and most declarative syntax I know for this task. But please add a better answer so I can learn how to without jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use `jQuery` (and you shouldn't add it just for that purpose), you can use the following simple code snippet. Further information about inserting an element into the DOM before another element can be found on the [Mozilla Developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
var afterElement = document.querySelector('.uvIdeaVoteBadge');
var parentElement = afterElement.parentNode;

parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement);
```

**Here is an executable example:**

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var newElement = document.createElement('span');
  var afterElement = document.querySelector('.uvIdeaVoteBadge');
  var parentElement = afterElement.parentNode;

  parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement);
});
```

```css
.parent-element {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.parent-element span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.uvIdeaVoteBadge {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-element">
  <div class="uvIdeaVoteBadge">.uvIdeaVoteBadge</div>
</div>

<button>add element before .uvIdeaVoteBadge</button>
```

---

#### Adding Multiple New Elements (addition from comments)

If you want to add a single element in front of every `<li>` tag, you can use the following snippet (beware, that only `<li>`s can be used inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>` according to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)):

```
var allListElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
allListElements.forEach(function (afterElement) {
   var newElement = document.createElement('div');
   var parentElement = afterElement.parentNode;
   parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement);
});
```

**Here is an executable example:**

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var allListElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  allListElements.forEach(function (afterElement) {
    var newElement = document.createElement('li');
    newElement.classList.add('new');
    var parentElement = afterElement.parentNode;
    parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent-element {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.parent-element li {
   color: white;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   background: green;
}
.parent-element li.new {
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-element">
  <li>old element 1</li>
  <li>old element 2</li>
</div>

<button>add new li in front of every li</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the really detailed answer. Sorry if I'm going out of scope for this one, though how would I change this to work with multiple <li> items? I have tried experimenting with `document.querySelectorAll()` without much luck here.

Comment: @LW001 I've updated the answer, adding a section about the usage of `querySelectorAll`. It basically returns an array of elements and you have to repeatedly do the actions of above.

Comment: That solution seems to only add it to the last element for some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery then this should work

```
$('.uvIdeaVoteBadge').before(something...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but there's a :before pseudo class

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before